# Не могу передать данные из другой формы

Tags: c#, form

Есть код:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm = this.Owner as Form1;
MessageBox.Show(frm.CaptureDevice.ToString());
```

Вот "CaptureDevice" в другой форме:

```
CaptureDevice = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

При компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на
экземпляр объекта."
```

Как исправить ошибку?
Спасибо!

Comment: а что должно быть по вашему

Comment: @SeeSharp Я хочу получить CaptureDevice из другой формы

Comment: public static прописать перед объявление пробывал

Comment: Вы скрыли член от других классов. Нужно сделать его публичным для всех остальных классов (форм)

Comment: Я чего-то логику не улавливаю. Зачем делать это `Form1 frm = this.Owner as Form1;` если потом вы делаете это `frm = new Form1();`, какой смысл тогда первого присваивания? Покажите весь код, а не его обрывки.

Comment: @SeeSharp я уже сделал его public

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указанная ошибка - это не ошибка компиляции, а исключение, которое возникает при обращении к полю, методу или свойству нулевого объекта (null).
Проблема скорее всего тут:

```
frm = this.Owner as Form1;
```

Вы зачем-то перед этим создаёте переменную со второй формой, а потом берете владельца первой формы и присваиванием в эту переменную. Уверен у первой формы владелец не определен и там null, поэтому в результате frm тоже null, отсюда и ошибка.

Судя по вашему коду, вы хотели у второй формы задать владельца - первую, тогда нужно делать так:

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Owner = this;
MessageBox.Show(frm.CaptureDevice.ToString());
```

Если дальше с прогой всё норм, то ошибки быть не должно.